# video.js change color dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video.js

I am working with video.js and I want to change the color of the different element (icon, text) dinamically.
First, I retrieve the value of my *iconsColor* variable which is in the HTML. Then, in the JavaScript, I do this, after the creation of the element in the DOM :

```
if (vjs.options.template != 4) {
        $(".vjs-author-control").css("color", vjs.options.iconsColor);
}
```

This is my HTML :

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-test-skin" controls  width="640" height="360" avatar="" bufferbarcolor="0x9A9894" controlbarcolor="0x4f4c4b" data-preroll="" data-midroll="" data-postroll="" displaytimeline="false" embeded="false" embedibox="true" enableairtv="true" enableembed="true" enablepub="false" enableshare="true" from="Lea" iconscolor="#DA5ADC" idparam="player_1111111" idvideo="111111" isliveid="false" lang="fr" logo="true" position="1" poster="http://www.supportduweb.com/page/media/videoTag/BigBuckBunny.png" preload="auto" preroll="undefined" prerolllink="undefined" progressbarcolor="0x0088C9" ratio="1.33" randomid="1234567891" regie="" shorturl="Fullmetal_Alchemist_Brotherhood_46_French_Xvid http://xfru.it/HD6lnd http://xfru.it/kmBTqV" slice="10" srcga="" start="0" stats="" style="height: 482px" template="1" urlsite="" urlvideo="/videoviewdemo_v2.html" urlvideohd="" vidtitle="Player de test" data-setup="{}" { "autoplay": false }>
         <source id='mp4Source' src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
```

This is how I create element :

```
vjs.Author = vjs.Button.extend({
    init: function(player, options){
        vjs.Button.call(this, player, options);
    }
});

vjs.Author.prototype.buttonText = 'Author';

vjs.Author.prototype.buildCSSClass = function(){
  return 'vjs-author-control' + vjs.Button.prototype.buildCSSClass.call(this);
};

vjs.Author.prototype.onClick = function() {};

vjs.Author.prototype.createEl = function(){
  var el = vjs.Component.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
    className: 'vjs-author-control',
  });
    this.content = vjs.createEl('div', {
        innerHTML: '<div class="vjs-control-content"><span class="vjs-control-text">Author</span></div>',
        'aria-live': 'polite'
    });

    if (vjs.options.template != 4) {
        $(".vjs-author-control").css("color", "red");
}

    el.appendChild(vjs.createEl('div').appendChild(this.content));
    return el;
};
```

I don't see any changing. There is another way to do this?

Comment: what you get color name?

Comment: could you post your html dom structure as well

Comment: @dreamweiver yes, I did it.

Comment: @Sid I am sorry but I don't understand your question :x.

Comment: @Daelis: hey bro, i cant relate your js code to the html structure , i mean i cant see any class like `.vjs-author-control` in ur html code

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Everything is created with the JavaScript, so I use protytpes to make the element and build the class. I'm going to edit my post and add the code which creates the element.

Comment: Can you post an example to jsfiddle or jsbin?

Answer (score 2):

I would really discourage you from just throwing new custom attributes on the dom element like this. At the very least, prefix them as data-attrs or something along those lines, but I would suggest putting things in the data-setup attribute. When I say "discourage" here, what I mean is, "you seriously shouldn't do this". The video tag you posted above is, to be blunt, nowhere near valid, which might be contributing to your debugging woes.

That being said, I don't see anywhere where you're actually specifying the `iconsColor` option for Video.js. If you're thinking it's done here: `iconscolor="#DA5ADC"`, it's not, unless you have something set up to look for custom attributes. Again, I strongly suggest you rework everything along these lines, but I'll focus on the icons color attribute for simplicity.

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" controls  width="640" height="360" poster="http://www.supportduweb.com/page/media/videoTag/BigBuckBunny.png" preload="auto" data-setup='{"iconsColor": "#DA5ADC"}'>
    ...
</video>
```

Comment: Hello Matt, thank you for answering me. So, concerning the iconscolor attribute, I have a get function which works so I think that is OK. I've got an old version of video.js and now, I am trying to use the last version of video.js to make a new one. In the last version, we used canvas to create all the elements (play button...) and with the custom attributes like iconscolor we changed the design. Indeed, I have made 4 different templates. I have to be able to modify some things like the color of the component dynamically. Do you have an idea to do this ?

Comment: I understand what you say Matt. Do you know how to change the color of the pseudo-element ?

Answer (score 0):

We have an interesting article that we go into how to use Javascript to change colors dynamically in real time. (We use kermit the frog as the subject!)

Check it out here: https://www.greatbigdigitalagency.com/blog/its-not-easy-being-bleen-a-color-changing-javascript-adventure